# ASP.NET MVC 2 Conditionally show model objects in my view depending on dropdownlist value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.NET MVC 2, I have a model for a view. The view has a dropdownlist of roles that is populated by the model and there is a list below that of checkboxes with a number of privileges. I want to show only specific privileges depending on the dropdownlist selected roleID and have it update the privileges everytime the dropdownlist changes. I know how to do this in web forms ASP.net with absolutely no problem but I cannot seem to figure out where to start in ASP.NET MVC. Can someone please advise me what I need to do or towards a tutorial that will show me what to do? I am a novice in MVC. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used to solve my problem was to call $.getJSON on the change event of the dropdownlist which returned an array that I looped through and determined if the privilege should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, you have complete control over the HTML markup used. In this kind of situation, I would mark each checkbox with a bit of metadata, and then when the change event occurs on your drop down, you enumerate over all the check boxes on the page and then show / hide them as appropriate.

Basically, you can push all that logic down to the client side, instead of having to make a round trip.

Comment: The problem that I run into is that the roles are not static and so the metadata would not be static. I essentially need to run a query against the db based on the roleID to see which privileges need to be shown and then loop through the checkboxes to see if the privilege is in the query results and if so show it.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Ajax and jQuery =D

Comment: Tejs, it was. I ended up using JSON.